# Is Heroku hosting incompatible with .net?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, azure, heroku, cloud-hosting

I have a Facebook application hosted in Azure coded in c#. But configuration in my Facebook application asks for Hosting URL: that must be hosted in Heroku. So my application can't post actions to Facebook because this error always pops:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

How is it supposed to work if I can't add my Azure URL: `app.cloudapp.net` as a hosting URL if only Heroku URLs are accepted.

Adding my applications's URL to the App Domains in application configuration hasn't helped either.

And strangely another application that I have works fine with no Hosting URL defined.

What I'm supposed to do to solve this, migrate everything to PHP? I know there can be another answer.

Comment: Are you sure your app isn't configured to point to heroku? that sounds like the error - your App Domain, Website Url or Canvas Url must be pointing to heroku

Comment: Agreed, Thuzie(sp) does almost al their facebook app hosting in Windows Azure without issue. So I suspect there's may be an issue in your app.

Comment: I just removed the Hosting URL leaving it blank and after one day it suddenly worked fine. So it seems that Hosting URL isn't necesary at all. And it was probably just about servers replication to get all of them aware about my new config. Thanks @Igy and BrentDaCodeMonkey.